# How to access local variable outside method Java?

Tags: java, android

I need to access string stream1 inside method, but its only works on method scope. I already declare its as global variable in class. Please see sample code below :

```
public class EmbeddedPlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String stream1;
    LowCostVideo xGetter;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_embedded_player);
        xGetter = new LowCostVideo(this);
        LowCostVideo xGetter = new LowCostVideo(this);
        xGetter.onFinish(new LowCostVideo.OnTaskCompleted() {
    
            @Override
            public void onTaskCompleted(ArrayList<XModel> vidURL, 
                                        boolean multiple_quality) {
                stream1 = "show me";
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                               stream1,Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                     .show();  // Its works showing text "show me"
            }
        });
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                       stream1,Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
             .show(); // Not works, its give NULL result
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`onTaskCompleted()` is a callback method. The Toast inside that method doesn't get called until the asynchronous task is completed. But the Toast at the bottom of `onCreate()` gets called right away, without waiting for `onTaskCompleted()` to finish. Simply defining a callback method doesn't mean the code will pause right there and wait for it to complete.

So if you want to set the value of `stream1`, you have to do it from `onTaskCompleted()`. And if you want to use the value of `stream1` later on, you'll have to somehow check that `onTaskCompleted()` has executed.  This could by by calling the method that uses `stream1` directly from `onTaskCompleted()`, or it could be by performing a null check on `stream1` before using it.

Asynchronous operations are one of the most difficult subjects in programming. There are a million ways to handle it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am very new on java programming, is that mean is not possible for access stream1 variable outside method? or any other solution for this problem.

Comment: You've declared `stream1` at the class level, so you can access it anywhere within the class. However, its value will be null until after `onTaskCompleted()` has executed. It's like trying to start a car before you put any gas in it.

Comment: The `onTaskCompleted()` callback sounds like it indicates that a video of some sort has loaded. So perhaps you'd start the Activity by showing a loading indicator, and then in `onTaskCompleted()` you'd hide the loading indicator and show the video stream.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not **how** you are accessing the variable.  The problem **when** you are accessing it.  Specifically, in the second toast you are accessing the variable *before* the `onTaskCompleted` callback has been called.

Basically, your `onCreate` method won't be able to make use of variables set by `onTaskCompleted` because the latter isn't being called until after the `onCreate` call has returned.

Note that `new LowCostVideo.OnTaskCompleted(){...}` is actually creating an instance of an anonymous inner class that gets passed to the `LowCostVideo` instance.  That instance's method only gets called when the `LowCostVideo` object completes a task.

Clearly what you are doing here is just a test.  In the "real" code you are going to have to figure out how to do ... whatever it is you are really trying to do ... in another way.

Comment: Yes i shrink the code to make me more easier understanding how the program works, because in real code i get confused. I am very basic in java. Thanks for your answer.